# Custom URLs for Facebook Ads not Showing Conversions in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, url-parameters, conversions, utm-parameters, facebook-ads-manager

I am using Facebook's dynamic url parameters in our paid ads and all metrics are showing except for conversion data (transaction/revenue) in Google Analytics. All the UTMs have validated and all parameters (source/medium/campaign) show correctly in Google Analytics as well. Just no conversion data. We use 'static' UTM codes all the time with no issues. Does anyone know what might be happening here? Is this a Facebook or Google issue most likely? Should I try using 'static' url parameters in our Facebook Ads and see if that works? Finally, we are using Google Analytics standard and enhanced ecommerce tracking.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that as long as the Facebook Pixel and Google Analytics Tag are properly installed and configured and that you have accounted for differences in attribution models, date-of-click vs date-of-purchase, cross-site device tracking & view-through conversions not being tracked by Analytics, etc. that there is little what you can do to fix the data discrepancy between this two platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so from what I understand, you want to track your purchases as conversion events and also then track the revenue, transaction details etc. Google analytics or FIrebase by default has events set up especially for this but which will only track your website or app transactions events if you set up their sdk/tracking events code. If you want to use your own events for tracking, you will have to set up something what Google calls - **Custom events**. For these custom events to show on your dashboard, you will have to set up BigQuery first to map these events and then would need at least 1000+ triggers or conversion for Google to start showing them. This is a big hassle.

Here's what I would suggest to you alternatively, which I am too using. Set up Segment.io for your website/app which will help you to track your events. Then with Segment.io as the source, make a destination for Amplitude.com to create charts and analysis to understand your product events. Segment basically helps you to set up custom events and then with that set up, you can send the triggers of these events to any destination you want. This saves the developer from coding multiple times for different platforms. You can send segment triggers to various destinations like facebook, google analytics, amplitude etc.